# does django saves Charfield as strings?

Tags: django

so basic and confused about this question.

i tried to see type of some objects in django and equals together .
see example below :

```
print(type(request.data['token']))
>>> <class 'str'>
```

and :

```
obj = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
print(type(obj.first_token))
>>><class 'app.models.first_token.token'>
```

obj.first_token is a charfield.
so how can i know that first_token stored as string?

```
if request.data['token'] == obj.first_token:
```

are this two objects equals if have a same value in them?
models.py

```
class FirstToken(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.token

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
        size = 6
        self.token ="".join(random.choice(chars)for _ in range(size))
        super(FirstToken, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """User Profile model """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
                            User,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name='user_profile')
    first_token = models.OneToOneField(
                               FirstToken,
                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                  related_name='first_token',blank=True)

def post(self, request,phonenumber):
        obj = UserProfile.objects.get(phonenumber=request.data['phonenumber'])

        if request.data['token'] == obj.first_token.token:
            obj.is_active = True
            obj.save()
            return Response({"message": "User has been activate"})
        elif request.data['token'] != obj.first_token:
            return Response({"message" : "Token not provided"},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(obj)
```

Comment: why not test the condition in a view and have it console print

Comment: You should show your model code. There is no way getting the contents of a CharField from a model directly loaded from the database would give you that result.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I posted as you request.

Comment: Well that very clearly shows that UserProfile.first_token is a OneToOneField, not a CharField.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sry i forget to mention the token self.i fixed that to obj.first_token.token .they are same str and values are the same but my obj.is_active = True doesnot work.see my views again tnx.

Comment: Well, again, `is_active` is not a field of the UserProfile model, but of User.

Comment: condition works and obj.is_active = True works to .even i print(obj.is_active) returns true and response message shows up.but user model is not active again.why is that happening? should i save the obj with args and kwargs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as daniel roseman said.obj hasn't `is_active` property.for saving.cause the userprofile has OneToOne relation to user django model. you should do this :

```
obj.user.is_active = True
obj.user.save()
```